# How do I count total of value in one column with different data

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a bit confuse how to name my question title.

Let say my MySQL database table like this. `table_group`

```
UserID  UserGroup  UserStatus
------------------------------
1       1          1  
2       1          1 
3       1          2 
4       2          3
5       3          2
6       3          1
7       4          3
9       4          4
10      4          1
```

I want to **group** it by `UserGroup` and **count** the `UserStatus`.

Let me know what is the correct statement to get the result like this

```
UserGroup  Status_1  Status_2  Status_3  Status_4
-------------------------------------------------
1          2          2        0         0
2          0          0        1         0
3          1          1        0         0
4          1          0        1         1
```

Comment: The keywords to search for: 'cross tabulation/crosstabs' and/or 'pivot table'. See also a list for [common mysql queries](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php), pivot tables are in there.

Comment: @Wrikken thank you so much for the keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `case` to count rows that match a condition:

```
select  UserGroup
,       count(case when UserStatus = 1 then 1 end) as Status_1
,       count(case when UserStatus = 2 then 1 end) as Status_2
,       count(case when UserStatus = 3 then 1 end) as Status_3
,       count(case when UserStatus = 4 then 1 end) as Status_4
from    table_group
group by
        UserGroup
```

Comment: Thanks. May I know what is the different between [marc answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724955/how-do-i-count-total-of-value-in-one-column-with-different-data/6724995#6724995)

Comment: @hmmmm: marc's answer relies on a `true` expression returning `1`; which, if true, would be be MySQL specific.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT UserGroup, count(UserStatus = 1) as Status_1, count(UserStatus = 2) as Status_2,
                  count(UserStatus = 3) as Status_3, count(UserStatus = 4) as Status_4
FROM table_group GROUP BY UserGroup
```